# Change fadeIn() colour from white to a specific colour

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if it's possible to change the default colour for .fadeIn() from white to a specific colour.

For instance the whole page fades in from grey and fades out to grey when clicking on a link. This is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').css('display', 'none');
  $('body').fadeIn(450);

$('a').click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  newLocation = this.href;

  $('body').fadeOut(450, newpage);

});



function newpage() {

 window.location = newLocation;

}

});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for replying. Basically, I want the page to fade to a light grey then the page elements would be displayed. Same goes with a fadeOut effect. This is similar to video production when editors have an option of fading to black or fading to white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a CSS issue, you can set a background colour on the HTML (grey by default in your browser) and a background colour on the BODY e.g. to fade in from red to blue

```
html{
    background: red;
    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @john! This actually worked! I just had to set the background to the html selector while still retaining the fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions! Great!

Answer (score 0):

```
function newpage() {
    window.location = newLocation;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css({'display':'none','backgroundColor':'lime'});
    $('body').fadeIn(450).animate({'backgroundColor':'yellow'},450);

    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('body').animate({'backgroundColor':'aqua'},450).fadeOut(450,newpage)
    });
});
```

you must use **jQuery UI**

---

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/d3a676bc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` in **jQuery** uses the *opacity* property and not *color* or *background-color* properties to make the fade effect, so if you want do that, do it with an absolute div which covers the whole page's content and give what you want as a `background-color`